# Relationship between diffused light and intensity

Tags: visible-light

I was wondering if the relationship of the intensity of diffused light is a linear correlation to the diffusing material. Basically will the intensity of the diffused light change in a linear fashion as the diffusing factor increases/decreases?

Comment: What does "diffusing factor" mean?

Comment: Maybe I have a confused understanding of how diffusion works but i thought different materials diffuse light more or less because of their properties. I am sorry but I don't know the name for the property that determines how much light is diffused.

Comment: Couldn't one *define* a "diffusing factor" $D$ such that $I_\text{transmitted}=\frac{1}{D}I_\text{incident}$? By definition, this would be linear. The interesting physics would then be to determine how $D$ depends on wavelength, thickness, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple model of a diffusive material is a material where there is a certain probabability per path length that a photon will be scattered in a random direction, similar to how a colored material absorbs photons with a certain probability per path length.

If the characteristic length of the material is $L=d^{-1}$, where $d$ is a "diffusivity factor" for the material, then it's easy to show that if the incoming beam is collimated, the amount of light that exits the material and remains collimated is
$$P_c=Pe^{-Td}$$
where $P$ is the power of the incoming beam and $T$ is the thickness of the diffusing material.

Meanwhile, the scattered light will be isotropically radiated, with an intensity
$$P_s=\frac{P}{4\pi}(1-e^{-Td})\approx \frac{PTd}{4\pi}$$
per steradian in the far field in the low diffusion limit $Td\ll1$. As a result, scattered intensity is roughly linear with diffusion factor (up to a point).

Comment: I apologize again for my lack of technical terms but if I understand your answer correctly, as long as the thickness of of the diffusing material times the diffusivity factor is less than 1, i could treat it as a linear function then?

Comment: @JulianG.: Yeah, as long as the fraction of light scattered is small, it should be linear in the diffusivity.